# comparison framework SOAP VS REST

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, document

I need to compare two responses, say one is in json and one is in xml format.

I am consuming two services and I need to compare and come up with result that showing the diffrences of that responses.

I need to write java program on this, can you please suggest any design, technology, tool on this.

Thanks

Comment: Read them into objects, compare the objects.

Comment: If you want to test Web Services in terms of Request / Response through Soap or Rest API or you want to Validate Performance attributes through Load test one of the most widely used tool is Soap UI which is free. SoapUI is supported by Groovy Script which is similar to Java. Try it out. Let me know if this answers your question. Thanks.